# Using git with a project in a Dropbox folder

Tags: git, version-control, github, dropbox

I'm struggling with a git project in a Dropbox folder.

I work across multiple PC's. To get around this I always work out of a Dropbox folder, this means wherever I go on whatever PC I can pick up where I left off.

This seems to cause problems for Git. Here's what i'm doing:

1. Add some files
2. git add .
3. git commit -m "Files added"
4. git status: No changes to commit
5. Let Dropbox sync up
6. Switch to another PC
7. Let Dropbox sync down
8. git status: Lists all files added on other PC as 'modified' even though they haven't been

How can I get around this behaviour without losing the ability to switch between workstations or use git?

I am also pushing the project to Github. I'm developing within a CMS so i've git-ignored all of the core CMS files that are never going to change. My repo only contains the files that are bespoke to the project. This means I can't just git pull the repo because it will be missing all the CMS files but it seems pointless to include the whole CMS and all the assets in the repo.

Just to be clear i'm not trying to use Dropbox as a remote repo which is all I can find on Google. My actual project that i'm working on is in a Dropbox folder, my remote repo is on GitHub.

I've attempted to use git a few times but can never find a workflow that works. If someone could help me out here i'd be grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a very bad idea, and from a bit of Googling, it sounds like you can potentially corrupt your repo as well.

The 'Right' way to do this, would be to use development branches.
When you finish work on one workstation, commit/push everything to a development branch.

Then on the second workstation, pull this branch and continue.

As features become ready, cherry-pick/squash the relevant commits into a release (usually master) branch.