# Keeping .git folder outside of dropbox

Tags: git, dropbox

Dropbox tends to have problems with git files. Making duplicates etc. However, I would like it to back up some elements that I may not necessarily include in my git repositories and also track changes that I haven't yet commit to git.

I have a great solution for this when it's a brand new git repo (`git init`)

I change directories to the project folder in dropbox and in a terminal:

```
git --git-dir=~/git_storage/my.git --work-tree=. init && echo "gitdir: ~/git_storage/my.git" > .git
```

It works exactly as I would expect. It replaces the `.git` folder in the working directory with a text file `.git` containing the directory in which the git files are actually stored. All of this - outside of dropbox. Leaving only the `.git` text file to be synced.

However, I'd like to know how to have the same setup (.git directory outside of dropbox) for a cloned or, already existing repository.

Comment: Possible alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1961515/227176

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using git with a project in a Dropbox folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19550657/using-git-with-a-project-in-a-dropbox-folder)

Comment: Both of those questions presume that the .git folder is in Dropbox. This isn't what I'm asking at all. Please review the question again, I've updated to add some more clarity.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE` environment variables before running your `git clone` command? Not sure if clone will respect those.

Comment: Alternatively, you might try the `--separate-git-dir=<git dir>` option of `git clone`. From `git help clone`: "Instead of placing the cloned repository where it is supposed to be, place the cloned repository at the specified directory, then make a filesytem-agnostic Git symbolic link to there. The result is Git repository can be separated from working tree."

Comment: Why not simply move the ```.git``` directory somewhere and then create a symbolic link in Dropbox to the new location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the repo already exists in Dropbox (ie, you cannot clone it with the `--separate-git-dir=<git dir>` mentioned by [charlesreid1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463213/charlesreid1)), you can:

- move the .git outside of DropBox
- set `GIT-DIR` to the new path of the .git

That way, you go on working in your Git repo (whose working tree remains in Dropbox like before), but your git commands will use the .git repo which is now *outside* Dropbox (even though [I had bad experiences before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9030201/6309), and [use `git bundle` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3633346/6309)).