# How do I track files outside of my git folder?

Tags: git

I am using the command

```
git --git-dir="C:\gitdir\path\remote-work-tree-test\.git" --work-tree="C:\worktree\path\testfolder" add .
```

to track files outside of my git folder and push them to my repo.

When I try to delete one of these files and run git add/commit/push, it does not delete the file in my repo.

I tried running a git status with the gitdir and worktree included but had no luck:

```
git --git-dir="C:\gitdir\path\remote-work-tree-test\.git" --work-tree="C:\worktree\path\testfolder" status
```

it says everything is already up to date.

I also found a [similar post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082105/keeping-git-folder-outside-of-dropbox) but I want to keep my .gitattributes and .gitignore files outside of the worktree. This post also leads me to ask if I even need --work-tree and if I can just use --git-dir by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

The first issue was that git wasn't storing any of my --git-dir or --work-tree values because I was using backslashes \ instead of forwardslashes /

second issue was that I needed to set add a `.git` txt file in the external folder I wanted to track. This file needed to link back to the `.git/` folder where I would be running my git commands from.

### .git

```
[core]
    gitdir = C:/path/to/my/git/folder/.git
```

then link to this new git file in my `.git/config` file with:

### .git/config

```
[core]
    gitdir = C:/path/to/my/external/git/file/.git
```

then it started working.... until I couldn't get the files to track properly. I would modify them and they wouldn't get updated after the initial add/commit/push

[so I dug deeper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71614155/10082088) and found that this set of commands is the easiest way (for me) to re-index my external folder and push the changes:

```
rm -r .git/index
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push
```

to go even further, I wanted to add `.gitignore` and `.gitattribute` functionality. [I dug more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1329476/10082088) and found that updating my external `.git` txt file was the best way (for me) to set up links to my `.gitattributes` and `.gitignore` files:

### .git (updated)

```
[core]
    gitdir = C:/path/to/my/git/folder/.git
    excludesfile = C:/path/to/my/git/folder/.git/.gitignore
    attributesfile = C:/path/to/my/git/folder/.gitattributes
```